# How do I move my OneDrive from C:\ to D:\?

Tags: windows-7, windows, ssd

Opened Windows Explorer in Windows 7 and see OneDrive under Favorites. Right click on Properties and I get these tabs, General, Sharing, Security, Previous Versions, Customize. Cannot do anything here. This looks like a ShortCut icon.
Went to C: to Users to GIGABYTE (computer name) to OneDrive. Right click on Properties and I get these tabs, General, Sharing, Security, Previous Versions, Customize.
I was able to MOVE other folders like Program Files & Program Files (x86) without any trouble.
I have SSD and would like to get OneDrive off of it. With files going here there will be too many writes & reads wearing out my new SSD.
The OneDrive on C:\Users\GIGABYTE\OneDrive does not have the same files in it as the OneDrive on D:\ProgramStorage\OneDrive. It is not “synced” with OneDrive on C:.

Tried to put .png here so that you could see, but will not let me.

Went to my other computer, desktop using Windows 8.1, and I can see the same files in its OneDrive that is in this OneDrive on C:\Users\GIGABYTE\OneDrive.

Comment: You have to change the OneDrive folder location within the OneDrive App/Program itself, not simply moving the folder.

Comment: This question is confusing since you talk about your Windows 8.1 machine.  There are some major differences between OneDrive on Windows 7 and Windows 8.1 I suggest you remove those statements to clarify your question.

Answer (score 2):

**Change the OneDrive Location in Windows 8 and Previous**

To change the OneDrive folder location in Windows 8 and previous versions, you have unlink OneDrive from your account and then repeat the setup process:

1. Right-click on the OneDrive icon in the notification area and then
   select Settings
2. Select "Settings" and then select "Unlink OneDrive"
3. Follow the setup process again and ensure to select the new drive or
       location to have OneDrive sync to; you must wait for your files to
       download again to the new location

[Reference](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/wiki/sdoptions-sdfileset/change-the-onedrive-folder-location/147dade2-830b-46ee-bf7e-36a8eab9446a?rtAction=1395561726606)

Comment: @Ramhound Fair enough, edited to remove references to SkyDrive

Comment: You could have kept the information about Windows 8.1 because there no longer is a OneDrive/SkyDrive notification icon in Windows 8.1 so those instructions were still helpful.  Since the name has changed its helpful to refer to OneDrive as its current name not the service formerly known as SkyDrive.